# i have create list view with file name with size but after then set on click list view they throw null pointer exception

Tags: android, file-io, android-listview

before to add file size its properly work but after then add this concept its showing error onclicklistitem below i give you snippet of code plz help me check my code and inform me.

list_file.xml********************************************************

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mylist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#aa0000"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

code***************************************************

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myList = new ArrayList<String>();   
    myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Recycle", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    file = new File( root_sd + "/recycle/" ) ;       
    File list[] = file.listFiles();

    for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
    {
        myList.add( list[i].getName() + "\n" + readableFileSize(list[i].length()));
    }

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList ));
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

     mFilePathTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.file_path_text_view);

        mStartActivityButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start_file_picker_button);
        mStartActivityButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    final File temp_file = new File( file, myList.get( position ) );   

    AlertDialog alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("File Detail")
    .setMessage("File Name:"+temp_file)
    .setPositiveButton("Delete",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                // do something when the button is clicked
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    DeleteRecursive(temp_file);
                    refresh();
                    //mylist.invalidateViews();
                    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            })
```

Comment: Where did you **initilize** the `listview` and where did you **setadapter** for the `listview`. Post the **full code** and **logcat** error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `myList.get( position )` now returns `filename + "\n" + size`. So when you do

```
final File temp_file = new File( file, myList.get( position ) );
```

you are now referring to something else.

Solution (hacky but should work):

```
final File temp_file = new File( file, myList.get(position).split("\\n")[0]); //updated
```

**Update**

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    File list[] = file.listFiles();
    final File temp_file = new File( file, list[position].getName());   

   ...
   ...
```

**Update2**

or simply:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        File list[] = file.listFiles();
        final File temp_file = list[position];   

       ...
       ...
```

Comment: its not working? still crashing? how about you change back to `myList.add( list[i].getName())` and see if it works? Will help to clear the doubts

Comment: yes its work myList.add( list[i].getName()) i think error in myList.get(position).split("\\n")[1] plz help me

Comment: So in that case, you understand why the problem is happening? because now `myList.get()` returns something else which is not the fileName.. see updated solution..

Comment: in temp_file print not correctly /mnt/sdcard/recycle/987.1 KB its replace my file name to file size after apply split plz correct split them

Comment: Should be 0? I see.. there are multiple ways to fix this problem.. haha!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

**1) declare this variable globally.**

```
private File list[] ;
```

**2) then in `onCreate()`**

replace this line

```
File list[] = file.listFiles();
```

with

```
list= file.listFiles();
```

**3) then in `onListItemClick()`**

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    final File temp_file = list[position];

    AlertDialog alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("File Detail")
    .setMessage("File Name:"+temp_file.getName())
    .setPositiveButton("Delete",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                // do something when the button is clicked
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    DeleteRecursive(temp_file.getAbsolutePath());
                    refresh();
                    //mylist.invalidateViews();
                    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            })
}
```